# Rails- How to deploy to another url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have migrated my Heroku app to the eu-region. But I cannot deploy to the new url. It deploys to the original url only. How can I specify with url to deploy to from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your file:

> .git/config

And change the url path under the [remote "heroku"]

sample:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "heroku"]
    url = #CHANGE HERE TO THE NEW ONE
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = heroku
    merge = refs/heads/master
```